# Phalcon is updating my foreign key to incorrect value

Tags: php, relationship, foreign-key-relationship, phalcon

I have a weird problem whereby one of my relations in my models is updating the foreign key to the wrong figure.

I have classes `Order`, `OrderProduct` and `OrderAddresses`.
The following:

```
$order_addresses = OrderAddress::find(array(
  "conditions" => "order_id = :order_id: and active = 'Y'",
  "bind" => array("order_id" => $order->getId())
));
foreach ( $order_addresses as $order_address ) {
  $order_address->save();
}
```

For whatever reason, before I run the code above, my foreign keys in the database are all correct, however when that code is run, the following SQL happens which sets the foreign key (order_id) to the number of a model that was used in the code previously:

```
UPDATE `order_address` SET `order_id` = ?, `address_id` = ? WHERE `id` = ?
```

I have no idea what is going on here and can't find a workaround.

`OrderAddress`

```
  public function initialize()
  {
    //use softdelete
    $this->addBehavior(new SoftDelete(
      array(
        "field" => "active",
        "value" => "N"
      )
    )); 

    parent::initialize();

    $this->belongsTo("order_id", "Order", "id", array(
      "alias" => "order"
    ));

    $this->belongsTo("address_id", "Address", "id", array(
      "alias" => "address"
    ));
  }
```

`Order`

```
$this->hasMany("id", "OrderAddress", "order_id", array(
  "alias" => "addresses"
));
```

As a workaround, I thought I would set the `order` again on the `OrderAddress` model by doing the following, however that didn't help:

`order_address->setOrder($order)`

Comment: what are you doing in `parent::initialize();` ?

Comment: What is the actual SQL that is executed (with the bindings filled)? It looks like your bindings are being messed up somehow.